# If div is empty, remove it and change class of next div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Some generated output can be as follows:

```
<div class="fivecol"></div>
<div class="sevencol">content</div>
```

if the div.fivecol is empty, I want to remove it and change the div.sevencol to a div.twelvecol

```
$('.fivecol').each(function() {
    if ($(this).html() ==''){
       $(this).remove().next('sevencol').removeClass('sevencol').addClass('twelvecol');
    }
});
```

doesn't do the trick. Any ideas?

Comment: The if condition is missing a closing `)`.

Comment: and also the close } bracket is missing in if condition

Comment: @nhahtdh thanks got it added to pseudo code, still doesn't work.

Comment: This is another solution that is based upon your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/8DR5Y/5/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.fivecol:empty + .sevencol').toggleClass('sevencol twelvecol')
                               .prev()
                               .remove();
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/JY9NN/

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign: Sure it does. Added a demo.

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign: Your question shows direct siblings. Is that the actual case? If not, change `+` to `~`, though this assumes separate containers for each group of `...col` elements.

Comment: works on your demo, but there's something not allowing it to work on my end... http://www.dirtybirddesignlab.com/TALO/news.php

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign: I get 404 for that link.

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign: I don't see any empty `fivecol` elements on that page. They all have nested elements.

Comment: At the bottom, under "No Image, stupid empty space" is an empty div.fivecol

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign: It has a nested `figure` element. Your question shows a `fivecol` with nothing at all.

Comment: Nope, figure element is removed in another line of js. When I inspect it I just see <div class="fivecol"></div> But I'll quit trying this stuff out so you can see what I'm seeing

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19734/discussion-between-dirty-bird-design-and-user1689607)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.fivecol').each(function(i, div) {
    if (!div.html().trim()) {
       div.remove().next('sevencol').removeClass('sevencol').addClass('twelvecol');
    }
});
```

basically I just fixed some syntax errors, and changed the `this` reference to the proper argument call. Let me know how that works.

Best,

-Brian

Comment: Please don't add signatures onto your answers.

Comment: @bwheeler96 - Get this error "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'html'"

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(function () {
    $('.fivecol').each(function() {
    if ($(this).html() =='') {
       $(this).remove();
       $('.sevencol').each(function(){
         $(this).attr('class','twelvecol');
       });
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: http://dirtybirddesignlab.com/TALO/News.php look at the last row, this is where the magic should happen

Comment: how did u check it, is it by viewing the page source

Comment: dev tools and the fact it doesn't span the width as .twelvecol should.

Answer (score 0):

We could use a couple fancy selector tricks:

```
$(".fivecol:empty + .sevencol").attr("class", function(){
    return $(this).prev().remove(), "twelvecol";
});
```

As you can probably guess, `.fivecol:empty` attempts to find an empty element with the class `fivecol`. It then proceeds to grab the sibling element, using `+`, which has the class `.sevencol`.

Once we have our `.sevencol` element, we set out to change its class value to `twelvecol`. Since we're in this function, we know that `.fivecol:empty` was found, so we can safely remove it. Lastly, we simply return the new class value to be assigned in the place of `sevencol`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cLcVh/1/